# load from a file object Enum

Tags: java

I would load from a file a string and put in in a object enum.

I create into a class this:

```
public Passenger{

private String pass_name;
public enum State{

b,c,d;

};
....

State reser;

public Passenger(String n,State r)
      pass_name=n;
      reser=r;
}
```

in another file I want read a file and put the string in the way i can create an object passenger such:

```
Passenger p=new Passenger(p_name,What should i put here)?
```

here is the structure of my file:

```
cod
passenger_name
reverved
```

cod and passenger will be rapresented by String while reserved should be rapresented through enum. I will read the file:

```
 BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname));

 String cod=reader.readLine();
 while(cod!=null){
      String p_name=reader.readLine();
      how can i load a enum type?

      Passenger p=new Passenger(p_name,What should i put here)?
      cod=reader.readLine();

 }
```

Comment: Please try to use code examples that are compilable and show your problem, or at least don't require a lot of modification to run them.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have code compilable.My problem is I don't know how read a string from a text file and load this string on a type enum when i create the object passenger

Comment: Your first sample code is also missing `class` before `Passenger`. It has a superfluous line with `....` to indicate missing code – either make that a comment or just leave it out altogether if it's not relevant. You're also missing the opening `{` in the constructor. "How can I load an enum type?" and "What should I put in here" should be in comments – the syntax highlighting also makes the placeholders easier to spot. And your second code sample has a line ending in a `?` which I guess is meant to end the question.

Comment: Leaving in placeholders for what you want to know is okay, but besides that, it's best to make your code as valid as possible. My preference is also to put any prose interleaved with the code, even if it's a placeholder description, into comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`YourEnumType.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) to convert the String you read from the file into the enum:

```
public class Passenger {
    public static enum State {
        New,
        Reserved,
        Paid
    }

    private String name;
    public State state;

    public Passenger(String name, State state){
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Passenger{name='%s', state=%s}", name, state.name());
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // line read from file
        String stateString = "Reserved";
        // convert string into state
        Passenger.State state = Passenger.State.valueOf(stateString);

        // create the passenger
        Passenger pass = new Passenger("John Doe", state);
        System.out.println(pass);
    }
}
```

(I took the liberty of making a cleaner version of your sample code.)

Make sure that the string in the file is the same as the name of your enum constant, including capitals, and that it doesn't include extra whitespace.

Comment: @user1055637 You should accept the answer that ends up solving your problem with the checkmark under the voting buttons.